# How do I integrate neo4j driver in node.js

Tags: node.js, neo4j

I want to use neo4j graph database with Node.

But I am getting error . Please help.

Error says neo4j is not defined.
But i have already installed the driver using npm

Here is my code :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = require('neo4j-driver').v1;   // neo4J driver


var app = express();


app.set('views',path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

// var driver =  neo4j.v1.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.v1.auth.basic('neo4j','test'));  // neo4j driver
// var session = driver.session();

const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'test'));

app.get('/',function(req,res) {
        res.send('it Works');
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log('Server Started on port 3000');

module.exports = app;
```

I am getting following error :

```
PS D:\Projects\neo4J_node> node .\app.js
D:\Projects\neo4J_node\app.js:23
const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'test'));
               ^

ReferenceError: neo4j is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Projects\neo4J_node\app.js:23:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
PS D:\Projects\neo4J_node>
```

Comment: And why is that surprising? Did you check the name you'd used for the import?

Comment: Oops. Thank you  jonrsharpe, for the help. It fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The drivers has been updated and the one you are using is no longer valid. Make the changes below and test it with session adding the test node to the neo4j. 
Change:

```js
var app = require('neo4j-driver').v1;   // neo4J driver
```

to:

```js
var neo4j = require('neo4j-driver')
```

to test the connection try this code:

```js
const driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost:7687', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'test'));

const session = driver.session()

const resultPromise = session.writeTransaction(tx =>
  tx.run(
    'CREATE (a:Greeting) SET a.message = $message RETURN a.message + ", from node " + id(a)',
    { message: 'hello, world' }
  )
)

resultPromise.then(result => {
  session.close()

  const singleRecord = result.records[0]
  const greeting = singleRecord.get(0)

  console.log(greeting)

  // on application exit:
  driver.close()
})
```